# Platform.js (Polymer), jQuery 2.x.x and Bootstrap - error

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, polymer, platform

I have a strange error after I've included Platform.js (v0.3.4) (Polymer), jQuery (v2.x.x) and Bootstrap.js (v3.2.0) on an empty page.

With Safari and Firefox, on some events, such as click or keyup, on the (empty) page, it throws an error :

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'elem.getAttribute( name )')

There is no problem with jQuery v1.11.1, and I didn't try other versions of Platform. Neither with Chrome or Opera.

If I replace all the 'click' by 'dblclick' in Bootstrap, there is no more error on click (it occurs on dblclick of course).

Well, it's no big deal but it is surprising.

Here is the code to test:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>PJB</title>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/polymer/0.3.4/platform.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
         <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If anyone have any idea of how to avoid this error without breaking Bootstrap, jQuery of Platform, I'ld be glad to know.

Thanks.

Comment: where are the events you mention defined?

Comment: They are defined in bootstrap.js. It's only the 12 lines of HTML I wrote.
But if I define other event such as `$('#el').click(function() {})`, the listener works, but it also throws the other error.

Comment: i see, funky. you shouldn't click on body anyway; bootstrap likes a viewport-wide container. i would guess that it's a delegated event under body that wigs out when it sees body as the target...

Comment: Yes, funky! Well, sure we don't click on the body, but to avoid the error, I would have to add `event.stopPropagation()` on every clickable and keyup-able (because Bootstrap uses a lot of those) elements on the pages. But I don't quite understand why Platform.js interferes with it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the problem is related to this issue: https://github.com/Polymer/platform/issues/69

The fix seems to be to wrap document and/or document.body. ex:

```
(function(document) {
  // add your jquery handlers here...
  $(document).on('click', ...);
})(wrap(document));
```

More explanation here: http://www.polymer-project.org/platform/shadow-dom.html#wrappers

Comment: Thank you. After some readings and tests, I basically wrapped all Bootstrap in the code you gave me. It perfectly works on Safari (and still on Chrome) I can show and hide Bootstrap's modals. But Firefox throws the following error `TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.getDefaultComputedStyle does not implement interface Element.` when I try to display a modal. It happens when we use the $ .css() function. I guess it's because I wrapped everything in the function, I'll try to only wrap the event listeners :)